# Magento 2 - REST API - searchCriteria in nested json file

Tags: rest, api, magento, magento2

I would like to filter out all orders with a specific `country_id`.

Here a sample from the `json` response:

```
{  
    "items": [{  
        "total_qty_ordered": 3,
        "updated_at": "2018-01-10 15:59:05",
        "weight": 0,
        "billing_address": {  
            "city": "Schaffhausen",
            "country_id": "CH"
        }
    }]
}
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
url = (
    "http://<host>/rest/V1/orders"
    "?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=country_id"
    "&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=CH" 
)
```

It's not working because `country_id` is in a nested entity.

So I've tried to replace `country_id` by `billing_address[country_id]` but it's not working either.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: @RafiqulHasan no unfortunately no solution found for this

Answer (score 3):

The default REST API for search is only searching for the column which is available in `sales_order` table.

You can not search with `country_id`, you will get an error like column not found. To make it work you have to customize the method `getList`

`magento/module-sales/Model/OrderRepository.php` by creating custom module OR you can build your custom API to fetch order details based on `country_id`

The proper URL

```
 http:/host/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=country_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=US&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

Method: `GET`

Header :

```
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization : Bearer <TOKEN>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the json structure for the search criteria..

```
{
"search_criteria": {
    "filter_groups": [
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "field": "attribute_name",
                    "value": [string|int|float],
                    "condition_type": [string]; optional
                }
                more entries
            ]
        }
        more entries
    ],
    "current_page": [int] page number; optional
    "page_size": [int] number of items on a page; optional
    "sort_orders": [ optional
        {
            "field": "attribute_name",
            "direction": [int] -1 or 1
        }
        more entries
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.